# Biber .blg file: APA referencing renders inline cite key, what am I missing?

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

```
\documentclass[a4paper,style=index,xindy,x11names]{book}
\usepackage[T1,LGR,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,russian,main=british]{babel} % Compile w/PDFLaTeX !!!!!
\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, useprefix=false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linktoc=all, colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    This is a sentence \cite{Festinger1957}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

```
@book{Festinger1957,
  title={A theory of cognitive dissonance},
  author={Festinger, Leon},
  volume={2},
  year={1957},
  publisher={Stanford university press}
}
```

My references render as the cite key, rather than in an APA fashion, which is what I think I have told LaTeX to do. [This excellent guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/269662) tells me to look for a `.blg` file, which I do not have.

The MWE above doesn't show it, but there is a glossary involved, so I compile: `pdfLaTex` → `makeglossaries` → `biber` → pdfLaTex → `pdfLaTeX`. With the exception of `biber`, all of these have worked for me before. I'm working with VS Code (1.71.2) and MikTeX (22.8.28).

What am I doing wrong?

Edit
LaTeX.tool:

```
{
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        }
```

I also tried without the `"env"`, which also did not work. I do have biber installed and updated according to MiK.

Comment: Do you mean citations in parentheses (typical for APA referencing)? If so, `\cite` should be rather replaced with `\parencite`.

Comment: Your example document works fine for me. I'm guessing biber is not being run, or run properly, despite your set up. If it were being run at all, you'd have a `.blg` file. Double check how you have VS Code set up to run these commands, and remember biber is run on the `.bcf` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
% !TeX TXS-program:bibliography = txs:///biber
```

before `\documentclass` and all, made the MWE run as expected. The actual document is still refusing, however.

Edit October 22, 2022: I think the whole thing breaks down because of the `\input{file.tex}` structure that I have going on.

Edit November 28, 2022: this is a work-around rather than a solution, I think, but let's go. [Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/), open up your project in VS Code (although something else will probably work as well) and run `docker run --rm --volume ${PWD}:/tex alexpovel/latex` in the terminal.

Then, compile like you'd normally do and ― voilà ― no more bold, in-line cite keys. (Although now I'm running into some glossary-related issues, but that's an issue for later.)